# How do I invert my function to return the input as output $v_{Out} = \frac {vIn - v_{Min}} { v_{Max}}$

Tags: inverse, inverse-function

I have an normalization function to convert values into a $0$ to $1$ range using the following function, but I'm stuck on how to turn the output into it's original format.

$$v_{Out} = \frac {vIn - v_{Min}} { v_{Max}}$$

Example:
$$0.25 = \frac {50 - 25} {100}$$

**How do I turn this output of $0.25$ back into the input of 50 using the inverse of my function?**

Comment: Assuming vMin and vMax are fixed, this is a simple linear equation of the form $y = (x-a)/b$. Your other questions here suggest you should know enough algebra to solve for $x$ in terms of $y$. (Hint: start by multiplying through by $b$.)

Comment: @EthanBolker I did figure it out after your hint so it is now x = (y * b) + a but on a somewhat related question what exactly is the difference between the way I'm normalizing of y = (x - a) / b and the common method I see of y = (x - a) / (b - a) and is there a correct method between the two?

Comment: Those two expressions are not the same. You should be able to tell them apart, either algebraically or with numbers, and decide which is correct.

Comment: @EthanBolker Obviously they aren't the same and produce different results which is why I was asking if one was seen as a correct method of normalizing. Maybe I didn't explain myself well enough but I have seen both forms of normalizing numbers and wasn't sure if there was a consensus or a better reason to use one over the other when it comes to normalization.

Comment: Your question did not ask which normalization to use, it asked about some elementary algebra, Which normalization is better depends on the context. What should $y$ be when $x = \text{vMax}$ in your application?